# Need Assistance Hosting on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I’ve just finished working on my first big personal project, bought a domain name, created an AWS account, watched a lot of AWS tutorials, but I still can’t figure out how to host my web app on AWS. The whole AWS thing is a mystery to me. No tutorial online seems to teach exactly what I need.

What I’m trying to do is this:

Host my dynamic web app on a secure https connection.
Host the web app using the personalized domain name I purchased.
Link my git repo to AWS so I can easily commit and push changes when needed.
Please assist me by pointing me to a resource that can help me achieve the above 3 tasks.

For now, the web app is still hosted on Heroku’s free service; feel free to take a look at the application, and provide some feedback if you can.

Link to web app:[my web app](http://biggie-beta.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 4):

> **You mentioned - The web app is still hosted on Heroku’s free service**

So, if you want the same thing in AWS, use **Elastic Beanstalk**.

> First Question: How to host my web app on AWS?

There can be multiple options to host your web app:-

1. **S3** Bucket to host your website.  [How to Host in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html)
2. **Elastic Beanstalk**. [Link](https://medium.com/hollowverse/how-to-host-your-app-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-b63d2c3f597d)
3. **ECS** - using containers
4. Single **EC2 Server** to host your website.
5. **EKS** - Kubernetes

By the way, there are many couples of things which you need to take care of before starting.

> Second Question, Host the web app using the personalized domain name I purchased.

If you have used S3, the hosted URL will be in HTTP and you can create a route entry in your purchased domain settings. If it is AWS,  create a new record in Route53.

If you host your website on EC2, you will get Public IP Address. Make a route entry with that Public IP.

If you have used ECS or EKS, you might require to use the Load Balancer and then you will have the Load Balancer DNS. Make a route entry with your Load Balancer DNS. Then again question will arise which kind of Load Balancer you want to use. [Like Application, Classic or Network Load Balancer]

If you use Elastic Beanstalk. It's a managed service, when you host you will directly get an endpoint. Make a route entry with that endpoint.

> Third, Link my git repo to AWS so I can easily commit and push changes when needed.

For this, you have to use **Code Build** and connect **Github** as a **Source** while creating Code Build Project. [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html)

For CI-CD, there are multiple things again.

As Heroku’s is a PaaS, which provides you the platform and but when it comes to AWS, it is an IaaS. So you get the infrastructure and when you get the provisioned infrastructure, there are so many things which you need to take care of like you have to think like an Architect. Prepare the architecture and then proceed. It requires knowledge of other things also networking, security etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll go over the options and resources you provided right away.

Comment: @ComfortSibanda Yes sure and let me know if you get any errors while doing that

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, the best way to host a web app in AWS is Elastic Beanstalk

But what is AWS Elastic Beanstalk and what does it do?

AWS Elastic Beanstalk encompasses processes and operations connected with the deployment of web apps into the cloud environment, as well as their scaling.
Elastic Beanstalk automates the deployment by putting forward the required capacity, balancing the load, autoscaling, and monitoring software efficiency and performance. All that is left for a developer to do is to apply the code. In these conditions, the application owner has overall control over the capacity that AWS provides for the software and can access it at any time.

So this is the best way to deploy the app and let’s follow the steps.

> Open the Elastic Beanstalk console and find the management page of your environment.

> Select “Upload and Deploy”.

> Select “Choose File” and choose the source bundle with the dialog box.

> Deploy and select the URL to open the new website.

You can use [CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-partners-github.html) to connect your Github and deploy your code

Conclusion

I have taken a simplistic approach and told you exactly what you need to do the required task without going into the hus and fuss of AWS. Saying that there is still a lot that can be done to bring the real value of your application in terms of balancing the load, scaling or improving the performance.